# react-router v5 – nested routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can't figure this out even when looking on SO answers. I have a layout that looks like this:

```
const Dashboard = (props) => (
  <div className={styles.views}>
    <Route
      to="/dashboard/reports/create"
      render={() => <ReportsForm {...props} />}
      exact
    />
    <Route
      to="/dashboard/reports"
      render={() => <Reports {...props} />}
      exact
    />
  </div>
);

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home, exact: true },
  { path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard },
  { path: '/about', component: About, exact: true },
  { path: undefined, component: Error404 },
];

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      {routes.map((config, i) => {
        const key = `path-${config.path}`;
        return <Route key={key} {...config} />;
      })}
    </Switch>
  );
};
const App = compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps),
)(() => {
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <IntlProvider>
        <Routes />
      </IntlProvider>
    </Router>
  );
})
```

I have a dashboard component responsible for rendering multiple tabs, so going to `/dashboard/reports/create` should only render the `ReportsForm` component, and going to `/dashboard/reports` should only render the `Reports` component. Currently both are rendered in both cases.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
When I try to print out the `match` prop in the Dashboard it gives me this – maybe this will be helpful:

```
{
  "path": "/dashboard",
  "url": "/dashboard",
  "isExact": false,
  "params": {}
}
```

Comment: wrap it in `Switch` inside `Dashboard`

Comment: Have you tried removing the DIV around the Routes?

Comment: @Rikin You mean nested switches? I thought this is not possible – will try right away

Comment: yes, since you are doing Route for Dashboard, new Switch would be inside Route > that renders Dashboard and then Switch > Route / Route

Comment: @Rikin This is giving me weird results – the first route inside the nested Switch is rendered, no matter whether I put `dashboard/reports` or `dashboard/reports/create`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from typo that you pointed out for declaring `to` instead of `path`

You can wrap `Dashboard` component `Route`s in a `Switch`

```
const Dashboard = (props) => (
  <div className={styles.views}>
   <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/dashboard/reports/create"
      render={() => <ReportsForm {...props} />}
      exact
    />
    <Route
      path="/dashboard/reports"
      render={() => <Reports {...props} />}
      exact
    />
   </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

If that dont work you can even wrap the entire thing in Route with initial path as follows:

```
const Dashboard = props => (
  <div className={styles.views}>
    <Route path="/dashboard/reports">   // <------------------
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/dashboard/reports/create" render={() => <ReportsForm {...props} />} exact />
        <Route path="/dashboard/reports" render={() => <Reports {...props} />} exact />
      </Switch>
    </Route>
  </div>
);
```

Here's the working example solution that I just created: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uih91e-router-nested?file=index.js

Comment: This is giving me weird results – the first route inside the nested Switch is rendered, no matter whether I put `dashboard/reports` or `dashboard/reports/create`. Wrapping the `Switch` in `Route` also does not help :(

Comment: I posted second example see if that resolves for you

Comment: Unfortunately not – as I wrote – wrapping `Switch` in a `Route` also does not help

Comment: Let me work on example in stackblitz for you. Apparently that's how I have it setup in my codebase and all seems to be working fine without issue.

Comment: I'm f*cking stupid. I declared `to` instead of `path` in my nested routes. This is the reason I'm sitting for more than 1 hour thinking wtf is wrong.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uih91e-router-nested?file=index.js

Comment: @Ancinek Ah I see there was a typo, I did not catch that. I changed that typo in my answer too along with posting link to working example. Let me know if it helped out, upvote accept whatever you like, cheers!

Comment: Yes, this indeed helped me as you suggested nested switch, and this is what I needed too! Thanks a lot!